# MVC Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have my controller working in a way at the moment where the url comes up `Home/Collections/Collection?id=1` at the moment, which was my intended functionality. However, I would now like to make the url more friendly. For example, I would like it to become `Home/Collections/Summer`.

I have the following code in my `CollectionsController`:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(Helper.Helper.ResolvePath("Collections"));
    }


    //
    // GET: /Collections/Collection?id=1
    public ActionResult Collection(int id)
    {
        var collectionModel = ds.GetCollection(id);
        return View(Helper.Helper.ResolvePath("Collection"), collectionModel);
    }
```

What do I need to change to get my desired result? Without having a separate `ActionResult` for each collection (as it will never be a fixed number)?

And here is my Global.asax

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

Comment: Post your route collection. You'll most likely need to add or modify your routing so accept a string instead of int parameter in the action method of the controller.

Comment: @danRhul What relation is "Summer" to the ID value of "1"? Is "Summer" the name of the collection? Do you want this route to work only for this one controller action? By using a custom route constraint you can do this but I'll need you to clarify before I give you the sample code for how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a route like,

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "Collections", // Route name
            "Collections/{name}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Collections", action = "Collection" ,id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Now in your CollectionsController,

```
public class CollectionsController : Controller
{      
    public ActionResult Collection(string name)
    {
      /// Your Logic here
      /// name is required parameter
      /// optionally you can add an id parameter
        return View();
    }

}
```

Now your url will be like "http://localhost:98765/Collections/Summer"

but i dont undersdtand why you need **Home** in the url

Comment: Didn't need Home in the url just put it there so people could understand

Answer (score 1):

Given the following `enum`:

```
public enum Seasons { Summer = 1, Fall = 2, Winter = 3, Spring = 4 }
```

Add a Custom Route to your route mappings:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "Home/Collections/{action}/{season}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Collections",
              action = "Collection",
              season = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult Collection(Season season)
{
    /* ... code ... */
}
```

Comment: The controller isn't Home but Collections. I also cannot have an enum as Seasons are specified in the database

Comment: @danRhul Nothing wrong with having an enumeration map the integer values defined in the database...

Comment: seasons can be edited in the database. It might now be Summer, it might be Summer/Fall and it will be changed constantly

Comment: @danRhul and your enumeration will reflect that change - Given `1 = Summer`, `2 = Fall` ...

Comment: @Xander...interesting. I shall have a go

Answer (score 0):

Change the `id` parameter to a string and do whatever database query is necessary to find the corresponding ID.

Comment: For the Collection ActionResult? Wouldn't that make it come up `Home/Collections/Collection?(string name)=name`

Comment: @danRhul: No.  MVC matches routes by parameter name alone. No matter what type `id` is, it will be matched by the `{id}` parameter in the route.  You can allow different parameter names by editing the routes.

Answer (score -1):

Along with [Manas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9585675/908607)' answer, you can have an additional "field/column/property" on your Collection to hold a URL friendly name.

Not all names will be URL valid names (for instance, if your Collection was "50% Off!!", you would certainly get unexpected results on the URL http://server/Collections/50% Off!!)

So you may want to try adding a "UrlFriendlyName" to your Collection, and generate it automatically from the official name:

```
public class Url
{
    public static string GetUrlFriendlyName(string name)
    {
        //Unwanted:  {UPPERCASE} ; / ? : @ & = + $ , . ! ~ * ' ( )
        name = name.ToLower();
        //Strip any unwanted characters
        name = Regex.Replace(name, @"[^a-z0-9_\s-]", "");
        //Clean multiple dashes or whitespaces
        name = Regex.Replace(name, @"[\s-]+", " ");
        //Convert whitespaces and underscore to dash
        name = Regex.Replace(name, @"[\s_]", "-");
        name = Regex.Replace(name, @"-+", "-");
        return name;
    }
}
```

That way, you can query your collection based on the URL Friendly Name (ideally, it will be unique but a whole lot of other concerns come into play... like adding the ID to the URL (http://server/Collections/Summer/1 or adding random numbers to the URL Friendly Name like http://server/Collections/Summer-123 or simply having the user who creates the Collection specify a unique URL Friendly name starting from the automatically generated one but failing back to the user if it's not unique).

Answer (score -2):

to have a URL like this Home/Collections/Summer you need to have a method called "Summer", and there you can have it return the ActionResult with the corresponding id to Summer, like this:

```
public ActionResult Summer() {
   return Collection(1); //where id 1 corresponds to summer
}
```

Comment: "Without having a separate ActionResult for each collection (as it will never be a fixed number)?"